# Save a list of Threads in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a question concerning the thread: 
In my activity I get a list of threads(more exactly a list of Runnable). Inside these threads, I check if the time written in the activity is the same as the current time (basically like an alarm).

When I press back on my android, my activity finishes and I go back to the main screen of my phone...however the thread are still there (which makes sense for me as it is initialized in the heap).

However when I return to my app, I have no way to get access back to these threads...
DO you have an idea how to do it?

Here is a part of my code:

```
public class SmartAlarm extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Runnable> listThreadAlarms;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        listThreadAlarms = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Alarm alarm: alarmList) {
        Runnable activateAlarm = new ActivateAlarm(this,(int)alarm.getId()-1,"alarm"+(alarm.getSound()+1),alarm.getTitle());
            Thread threadAlarm = new Thread(activateAlarm);
            listThreadAlarms.add(activateAlarm);
            threadAlarm.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should rethink your design. more on this to follow...

### I Do NOT Recommend This

if you **MUST** retain references to these objects, one way to do this is to stash them as instances in a static collection in a long-lived singleton. a custom `android.app.Application` instance would be an option since it lives for as long as your app does and you can reference it from any standard component such as an `Activity`, ie:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static List<Runnable> runnables;

}
```

- add `Runnable` instances to the collection as they are created...
- ...however, i have no idea what the criteria would be for removing them. `Runnable`s are meant to run to completion/error, and then be GC'd. since they don't return a result, we'd need some sort of state within the `Runnable` instance to know if it has completed its work, which means it can then be removed from the collection so as to be GC'd. by keeping them in this collection, they live beyond their scope of viability, and we've created extra housekeeping for ourselves in pruning the collection.

this sort of approach would *technically* work, but strikes me very odd and untestable.

---

### I DO Recommend This

let the `Runnable`s communicate the state of their tasks independently through another medium, ie:

- shared preferences
- a database
- an in-memory collection stored in the `Application`

when your `SmartAlarm` instance starts, interrogate the state of the associated tasks through that medium.